# std::stringstream vs std::string for concatenating many strings

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I know one of the advantages of `std::stringstream` is that it is a `std::istream` so it may accept input from any type that defines `operator<<` to `std::istream`, and also from primitives types.

I am not going to use `operator<<`; instead I am just going to concatenate many strings. Does the implementation of `std::stringstream` make it faster than `std::string` for concatenating many strings?

Comment: In comparison to what? `.append()`/`operator+=`?

Comment: I think a .reserve() followed by multiple .append()/+= should be quite efficient. Strings aren't immutable in C++ like they are in Java/C#/etc, so there isn't any reason to have a StringBuilder type class.

Comment: @Rapptz Yes. `append()` and `operator+=`

Comment: @Bwmat I have no clue of what will be the final size, actually

Comment: Well, even without the reserve, it shouldn't be too bad. I'm hoping that they do the same thing as vector, and grow the size exponentially, but I'm not sure.

Comment: did you mean `ostream` rather than `istream`?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There's no reason to expect `std::string`'s appending functions to be slower than `stringstream`'s insertion functions. `std::string` will generally be nothing more than a possible memory allocation/copy plus copying of the data into the memory. `stringstream` has to deal with things like locales, etc, even for basic `write` calls.

Also, `std::string` provides ways to minimize or eliminate anything but the first memory allocation. If you `reserve` sufficient space, every insertion is little more than a `memcpy`. That's not really possible with `stringstream`.

Even if it were faster than `std::string`'s appending functions, you still *have* to copy the string out of the `stringstream` to do something with it. So that's another allocation + copy, which you won't need with `std::string`. Though at least C++20 looks set to remove that particular need.

You should use `std::stringstream` if you need *formatting*, not just for sticking some strings together.

Comment: So what do I use if I only need to stick some strings together? I know exactly the size of the resulting string so I would like to preallocate it, but the code that sticks strings togethers requires an OStream and uses `<<` for concatenation (it works with `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, `std::stringstream`) but it doesn't work with `std::string`. Do I really need to write a small wrapper around `std::string` just for this?

Comment: I just wrote a small wrapper around a std::string with an `operator<<` that concatenates and that worked just fine. I just reserve the final size and after concatenating I move the string out. Feels like the stone age: string has `append` and `operator+` while `streams` have `write` and `operator<<`...

Comment: Please do add some benchmarks to support your answer.

Comment: While stringstream is not inherently faster, it is easier to use in an efficient way (avoiding temporaries / dynamic memory allocations) when it comes to concatenating strings. See https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/optimized-c/9781491922057/ch04.html (Chapter 4 of the Book "Optimized C++" by Kurt Guntheroth)

Answer (score 0):

In a recent set of benchmarks conducted on `Quick-Bench`, `std::stringstream` demonstrated lower performance compared to concatenating strings using the `std::string +=` operator. This is a notable finding because appending multiple strings and literals is a frequent operation in string processing.

The benchmark compared the two methods under identical conditions with the goal of concatenating a long string composed of literals and small string objects. The results indicated that std::stringstream is less efficient.

Please find the detailed benchmark results here:

https://quick-bench.com/q/iR8hY3MmHXCSXe5vvY28C-6mQfY

It's important to note that while `std::stringstream` showed worse performance in this specific test case, actual performance can vary. Factors such as the compiler version, optimization settings, and the underlying hardware can all influence the results. Therefore, it is recommended to run benchmarks tailored to your application's specific use cases to determine the best approach.